# Swift: mutate cast parameter (Error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'MyObjectType' (aka 'Dictionary<Int, Int>')

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary

I have a functions where I passed in Dictionary [Int : Int] as inout T and would need to write into the Dictionary.  This function is included as a function of a protocol.

However, after casting T into MyObjectType (Dictionary), it becomes immutable.

Question:  How can I make a generic parameter (it can be passed in as struct, class, array or dictionary) mutable after casting?

```
typealias MyObjectType = [Int : Int] // Key is a enum with Int as RawValue

static func myGenericFunction<T>(_ object: inout T) {    
    (object as! MyObjectType).updateValue(0, forKey: 1)    
}
```

I have tried casting it to NSMutableDictionary as below which compile successfully but crash when running with simulator.

```
(object as! NSMutableDictionary)[Int(pMetric.selectedUnit)] = Int(pMetric.metricType)
```

Thanks for any good solution!

Comment: Actually a generic function which casts the generic to a static type doesn't make sense.

Comment: This looks like a broken protocol. There's no useful way to implement `myGenericFunction`. If it requires an `as!` cast to implement, then the protocol is incorrect. What you're trying to do isn't directly possible, but the requirement also doesn't make sense. Take a step back and discuss why `myGenericFunction` has this signature. I suspect this protocol meant to have an associated type rather than a generic.

Comment: @RobNapier, you are right.  The problem I have is that the calling function to myGenericFunction is a GenericFunction :

func callingGenericFunction <P: someProtocol, T> (_ protocolClass: P.Type, _ objects: inout T) {
.....
protocolClass.self.myGenericFunction(&object)
}
I agree that associatedtype would make sense in the above myGenericFunction instead.  However, I have then the issue converting the type from the callingGenericFunction to pass object into myGenericFunction.  
I'm new to Swift and any proposal is appreciated.